# Upgrading from 2.0.6 to 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, docker

I'm currently experiencing bugs when trying to upgrade my dockerized installation of Magento 2.0.6 to Magento 2.2.4

I've imported the latest dump from production to the Docker Env and proceeded with the upgrade via composer.

After doing so I've cleared the cache and did one `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. This is the console output:

```
Upgrading data.. 
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Upgrading data.. 
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Vendor_Module3':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Upgrading data.. 
Module 'Vendor_Module4':
Module 'Vendor_Module1':
Module 'Vendor_Module2':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Upgrading data.. PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/html/app/etc/config.php on line 1

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/html/app/etc/config.php on line 1

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.root@9c09d9df7a7e:/var/www/html#
```

How can I increase the RAM in order to resolve this issue? Whats possibly wrong here? There's enough RAM available to the system.

Comment: If you know how to solve : Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
Message: cart is not a function
    at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted**

Magento 2 has memory limits defined in the root `.htaccess` file. These should be sufficient in production but may cause issues when running large installation scripts when developing your site.

Adjust memory limit

> php_value memory_limit 768M
>
> php_value max_execution_time 18000

Increase the memory limit in your `.php.ini` file
If you have access to your `php.ini` file or can create one in the root, you can globally increase your allocated memory.

**adjust memory limit:**

> memory_limit = 2G
>
> max_execution_time = 36000
>
> max_input_time = 36000

Aslo you can use :

> php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento Your_command

Comment: Good answer with addition to my one, i'll mark yours as correct as it contains more informations on that matter! Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

That was easy:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```